# how to use and store token from oauth2 to do authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

sorry if this is question is too broad, but I have to ask this since I'm learning web development and I feel if don't ask I won't know.

So, I'm doing authentication using oauth2, and right now I'm already at point where I successfully authenticate user, and now I'm receiving what they call tokens. The question is, how do you use token to authenticate user to your own server?

I'm thinking something like creating a cookie that maps to a token, so when user acts, each time I'll get a cookie and I know that this is user A. Is method like this safe or not? If not, in what way people usually use the token? Although this is only a hobby project, I'd like to be "as real as possible". Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge Oauth2.0 provides InMemoryTokenStore and  JdbcTokenStore for persisting tokens. When a request comes from an authenticated user Oauth2.0 will check if it has a valid token already. In case it doesn't it will create one.

Basically usage of tokens depends on the grant-type you are using . Following are the two commonly used grant types -

1) Implicit  - The token is send back in the url as a parameter and is included in the subsequent request* in the parameter.
2) Authorization Code - In this case the token is generated and set in the header of the request*.

*the request here is the one which is finally sent to resource server for accessing protected resources.

I think you dont need to create a cookie for storing tokens. In case you are using  Authoziation Code grant type which is the default, Oauth2.0 will use session for storing state and code which will be used for retrieving token.